# Can you plot the accuracy graph of a pre-trained model? Deep Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Deep Learning. I finished training a model that took 8 hours to run, but I forgot to plot the accuracy graph before closing the jupyter notebook.

I need to plot the graph, and I did save the model to my hard-disk. But how do I plot the accuracy graph of a pre-trained model? I searched online for solutions and came up empty.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of framework did you use and which version? In the future problem, you may face, this information can play a key role in the way we can help you.

Unfortunately, for Pytorch/Tensorflow the model you saved is likely to be saved with **only the weights of the neurons**, not with its history. Once Jupyter Notebook is closed, the memory is cleaned (and with it, the data of your training history).

The only thing you can extract is the final loss/accuracy you had.

However, if you regularly saved a version of the model, you can load them and compute manually the accuracy/loss that you need. Next, you can use matplotlib to reconstruct the graph.

I understand this is probably not the answer you were looking for. However, if the hardware is yours, I would recommend you to restart training. 8h is not that much to train a model in deep learning.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!